# Знаки, пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки препинания нужны в этих предложениях и нужны ли вообще?

Сказки Пушкина "Жених", "Золотой гребешок", "Сказка о попе и о работнике его Балде". Предполагаю, что здесь после Пушкина должно быть двоеточие.

Магическое свойство привораживать любовь. (Здесь сомневаюсь в надобности тире после свойство)

Comment: Домашнее задание?

Comment: Согласно правилам, мы не выполняем домашние задания, а просим предложить свой вариант ответа, который потом исправим в случае необходимости.

Comment: Также желательно для каждого предложения задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Это не домашнее задание. Просто я перфекционист. И даже если пишу для себя, люблю во всем точность.

Comment: Предполагаю, что здесть должно быть двоеточие: Сказки Пушкина: "Жених", "Золотой гребешок", "Сказка о попе и о работнике его Балде".

Comment: А здесь я сомневаюсь в надобности тире. Магическое свойство -привораживать любовь.

Answer (score 1):

А предложения написаны целиком или там ещё что-то есть?

*Сказки Пушкина "Жених", "Золотой гребешок", "Сказка о попе и о работнике его Балде"*. Если это название, то это не предложение, никаких знаков не нужно.

Двоеточие было бы в предложении с обобщающим словом: Мне нравятся многие сказки Пушкина: "Жених", "Золотой гребешок", "Сказка о попе и о работнике его Балде". В Вашем примере сказуемого нет. Можно расценить как односоставное назывное, но тогда названия сказок будут являться однородными приложениями - двоеточия нет.

*Магическое свойство привораживать любовь*. Тоже нужен контекст. Если это односоставное назывное,то *привораживать любовь* -распространённое определение: свойство какое?.Тире не нужно.Если двусоставное, должен быть другой порядок слов:*Привораживать любовь -(это) магическое свойство.* Сравните: *Поздний вечер* - назывное. *Вечер поздний* - двусоставное с составным именным сказуемым. В данном примере действительно тире не нужно.